# Paragraph between header fields

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created an header with the chapter number (Capítulo 1.) and title (Introdução). When I insert the name "Field" word creates a paragraph between this field and chapter number field.

How can I remove this paragraph and put "Fields" on the same line?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details. We can not see the formatting with this image. Are there any tabs after the chapter number? What fields are you inserting and how are you inserting them? Please use the [edit] feature to update your question with more details.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: It doesn't appear you saved the edit. The last edit was mine. Please try again.

Comment: Remove the blank space, reduce it